# Getting reminders of expired activities

Tags: activities

Activities in Cases (or even without) often have dates which serves as due dates or deadlines. In a few views (Manage Case and the case Dashboard e.g) expired activities stand out because they are rendered in red.

To get more visibility of expired activities I'd like to send a reminder email to the assigned contact when an activity expires.

I search for this but could not find anything on that topic, does that functionality already exist?

(Also, everywhere an activity is shown it should render in red if expired. This does not happen specifically in "Search Activity" and "Search Case". I assume I'd need to put that as a feature request. Or PR.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheduled reminders functionality should do the trick

Administer > Communications > Schedule Reminders

[image]

The scheduled reminders functionality relies on the ‘Send Scheduled Reminders’ scheduled job so it must be enabled.

Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs